# С++ : Ошибка C2039

Tags: c++

`name` не является членом `std::vector<man,std::allocator<_Ty>>`. Вроде решения находил, но в моем случае не спасло.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct man
{
    int score;
    string name;
};
bool scoredd(man a, man b)
{
    return a.score > b.score;
}
int main()
{
    string  guyy;
    int n, f = 0;
    cin >> n;
    vector <man> person(n);
    getline(cin, guyy);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        man struct_temp;
        int d = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        string  guy;
        getline(cin, guy);

        for (auto c : guy)
            d++;

        while (j < d)
        {
            if ((guy[j] >= '0') && (guy[j] <= '9'))
                k = k + (int)guy[j];

            j++;
        }

        struct_temp.name = guy;
        struct_temp.score = k;
        person[i] = struct_temp;
    }

    stable_sort(person.begin(), person.end(), scoredd);

    for (auto c : person)
        cout << person.name << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Вопрос, который вы должны были сами задать себе: зачем у вас в цикле заведена переменная `c`, если она нигде в цикле не используется?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (auto c : person)
    cout << с.name << endl;
```

Давайте более логичные имена. `person` в вашем случае не один человек (каковым является в данной ситуации `c`), а целая толпа... Это, наверное, вас и подвело - вы решили, что имеете дело с конкретным объектом.

А вообще-то, компилятор все правильно и весьма понятно рассказал: что члена `name` у вектора нет.

Comment: Да , мой косяк . впервые таким сайтом пользуюсь , привык чисто для себя делать) Тем не менее , программа вдруг стала работать , теперь она не видит никаких ошибок... Что это за магия такая?

Comment: Вы код исправили? Тогда какая же магия?

Comment: Ну я всего лишь поменял везде person на people и все. Не думаю , что изменение названия переменной могло все изменить , хотя по-видимому могло ... В любом случае спасибо за совет , надо действительно стараться давать переменным соответствующие названия , чтобы не путаться лишний раз.

Comment: @Dmitry: Вы что-то выдумываете. От замены person на people ваш код компилируемым стать никак не мог.

Answer (score 1):

Однако в вашем коде много лишнего, кроме ошибки, на которой указал пользователь `Harry`. Его можно улучшить  например так:

```
multimap< int, string, std::greater<int> > person; // сортирует по компаратору больше
string  guy;    
while (getline(cin, guy))
{  
    int k = 0;
    for (char c : guy) {
        if (isdigit(c))
            k += (int)c;
    }
    person.insert(make_pair(k, guy));
}
cout << endl << endl;
for (auto p : person)
    cout << p.second << endl;
```

Код короче, понятнее, меньше затрат на память, и конечно, быстрее.